# creating array of structures in c

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, structure

i am tryaing to create an array of structures from an input i get
like if the user enter 5 
so i need to bulid 5 structures and initializing them
this is my sturct in a header file

```
typedef struct abc
 {
pnt* head;
int number;
int number2;
float sum;
}abc;
```

and in my main file
i put

```
abc *t;


printf_s("How many strucures?:\n");
scanf_s("%d", &stru);
for (i = 0; i < stru; i++)
{
    t[i].head = NULL;
    t[i].number = 0;
    t[i].number2 = i;
    t[i].sum = 0;
}
```

and i get 
"uninitialized local variable 't' used"

Comment: A pointer is no an array (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abc *t;
```

here `t` is a pointer and it is not initialized. To initialize it:

```
scanf("%d", &stru);
t = malloc(stru * sizeof *t)
```